# Computer crashes on startup of 3D games

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, power-supply, crash, gaming

My computer renders games similar to Minecraft just fine, but games with more intensive graphics like:

- **Planetside 2**
- **Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon Phantoms**
- **Skyrim**

it crashes the instant it needs to render something. Games which also render 3D like:

- **Minecraft**
- **Team Fortress 2**
- **Garry's Mod**
- **Unturned 2**

give no problems. I've tried the following steps:

- disabling anti-virus : Kaspersky
- updating the drivers
- Checking that my computer is not overheating.
- Using diffrent power supply cables

  - I live in South Africa, where the wall outlet's voltage is 220-230 Volts AC, whereas the US is 120 Volts AC
- RAM tested, rises to 50% when games are running, 36% when not
- BlueScreenView tried, crash doesn't give a Minidump file
- Uninstalled PhysX

One strange thing which occurs is when I play Unturned. When I exit the window and open another tab, and return to Unturned, the screen freezes for about 2 seconds and then the computer crashes. Something that also occurs is that when my computer just turned on all games run fine.

When the computer crashes, it doesn't show a blue screen. It instantaneously turns the screen black and all the fans stop working. Then it restarts. The computer turns back on without me doing anything. **THEN** it shows a **black** screen which says "Windows has crashed because of an unknown error".

> OS:       Windows 7 64-bit
>
> Graphics: GeForce GTX 650
>
> RAM:      8 GB

Comment: Did it work without issue previously? It sounds like you have a PSU that's not supplying enough power or an overheating issue with your GPU

Comment: Uninstall PHYSX.

Comment: The problem seems clear. The difference between these games are OpenGL vs Direct X.  Since the computer is crashing, its generating a mini-dump file, use BlueScreenViewer to provide us more information about which drivers are loaded at the time of the crash.

Comment: This is too broad IMO.  Start troubleshooting: Check the Event Log for events related to the shutdown. Test RAM for 24-48 hours (MemTest86+).  Test drives (use drive manufacturer's utilities, and/or Windows' CHKDSK). Try another (known-good) video adapter.  Try these things we're suggesting, and then come back and edit your question to include what you tried and what the results were, to try and narrow it down.

Comment: Updated. I don't see why a video adapter would change anything, care to explain?

Comment: @Ramhound, BlueScreenViewer doesn't work unfortunately. When the computer crashes, it doesn't show a blue screen :/

Comment: @Christoffellis Video adapter is responsible for rendering 3D games so different video card might change everything. And actually it sounds like it, your video adapters driver crashes and cannot recover from it hence the black screen, automatic restart and no BSOD. Such critical crash indicates hardware failure or overheating. I suggest trying different video card, at least trying built in one (if present) or other dedicated one. If that's not the case then check processor cooling.

Comment: @Little Helper, is there a cheap way to test if this is the case? Is it hard to test, because I only have the one graphics device... Wait, if it is set to 32-bit, and my computer is 64-bit, will it make a diffrence?

Comment: I believe you can leave your hardware with your contacts at any local computer workshop for testing. I can, in my small town, plus for free.

Comment: @Christoffellis - You cannot load 32-bit device drivers on a 64-bit operating system

Comment: @Ramhound, on dxdiag the program says: **"Current display mode: 1440 x 900 (32-bit) (60Hz)"** what does it mean?

Comment: means the dxdiag is running in 32-bit mode.

Comment: But my device is running 64-bit?

Comment: @LittleHelper, if I do need to get a new graphics card, which would you suggest? Or do you think that the graphics card could be fixed?

Comment: I am bad at suggesting and it's a rare chance that the video card can be fixed. But we don't know if it's the video cards fault, right? Maybe something is happening with drivers? Uh?